# Combinatorial exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A group of 15 people go visit a city with 150 bar. At the end of the day one of those bar contains 8 people, the another one contains the other 7 people. How many ways can we get this situation? Explain why

My attempt:

$\binom{15}{8} * \binom{15}{7} * 150 * 149$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We choose can choose $8$ people from $15$ at $15 \choose 8$ ways and direct them to one of the $150$ bars.

There are 7 people left so there is ${7 \choose 7} =  1$ ways to send them to one of the $149$ bars left.

We later on use multiplication principle to obtain the answer.

The correct answer is ${15 \choose 8}{7 \choose 7}\cdot 150 \cdot 149$. (after rearragement).

Comment: Ok, but should it be multiplied by 149 instead of 140?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be 149.

Comment: Do you fully understand the answer or would like to hear some more comment on it?

Comment: Well I did understand, but a whole explanation would be really accepted!